Use R to generate a sequence random numbers of Poisson distribution with different mean
In R, how to use rpois generate, for instance, 5 random numbers from a Poisson distribution with mean 2, and then 3 random numbers from a Poisson distribution with mean 3, and put them in one vector of length 8?
I have tried
rpois(c(5,3),c(2,3))

but this generates a vector with length 2.

rpois(8, c(2,2,2,2,2, 3,3,3)) would do it.  There are many other ways to generate the vector of means, but for this length you may as well just write it out.

@user2554330 Thanks for your comment! May I wonder whether this syntax follows from some general rule of R? I did not see that way of using rpois on the document of the function https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/Poisson.html .

@Asigan:  yes, lots of R functions accept vectors for parameters and apply them successively to the vector result.  ?rpois says lambda (the mean) is a "vector of (non-negative) means".

There are lots of ways to do this. The most transparent one might be
rpt_vec <- c(5,3)
lambda_vec <- c(2,3)
rpois(sum(rpt_vec), lambda = rep(lambda_vec, rpt_vec))

sum(rpt_vec) is the total number of deviates you want; rep(...) generates the right number of copies of each lambda_vec value.

Just a suggestion:  an explicit calculation of the means vector (e.g. means <- rep(lambda_vec, rpt_vec)) and then using rpois(length(means), means) would be even clearer.
